# MySQL Connection error Google Cloud

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I deploy a node + sql application I made testes running the node app in my laptop using mysql database provided by google and the application was working fine (I needed to allow my ip address to connect) but when I deployed the application I started to receive timeout errors in my app. I solved the problem allowing any ip address to connect in my google cloud mysql instance but I not happy with this solution. Anybody can help to allow just the production node app server ip?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your API key to only be accessed from a certain IP, you can restrict it in the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials).

[image: Key restriction setting]

Comment: Ok but what ip I need to fill in the form? How I don't know the container ip address I inserted 0.0.0.0/0. The app is running fine, but I prefer limit the allowed ip address for a low number of ips.

Comment: @MauricioSilvestre you should know the IP address of your servers. If your containers are dispatched on a variety of servers you could also use a long & random HTTP Referrer to identify your servers.